# Use xcode copy files build phase to copy an entire directory

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.5

In Xcode 4.5, the only way I can see to copy a whole directory in a build phase (other than a custom bash script) is to add that directory to the project using "create folder reference", and add it to the "copy bundle resources" build phase. However this gives me no choice what name or location this folder is put.

The "copy files" build phase lets you copy files wherever you like, but I cannot see any way to add whole directories or groups to it... I can't drag-drop these in to the list, or add them manually, only individual files.

Is it possible to specify a directory to be copied, *and* where it should be copied to?

Answer (score 0):

The best way I know is to create a script that you call during a "run script" build phase that you can add. Here are directions on how: http://runscriptbuildphase.com/

Then if you want you can pass in variables to that script using the xcode user environment variables such as ${SRCROOT}.

I've used scripts like this to pull content from a repository and then package it with the build based on my environment variables.

Comment: That was my old way of doing things, my fall-back plan :)